# Knejx Js only promises

Tags: node.js, express, knex.js

how to make this function work. Only a promise comes back to me.

```
codeProducts.forEach((code, index) => {

    const qt = app.db('products').where('code',code).first().then(result => result.quantity)
      data[index] = {
        code: code,
        quantity: qt
      }
    })


    return data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two or three ways that you can solve this-

#### Approach: 1

I will make just one call to database.(I love my database :D) as-

```
let codeProducts = [55, 68, 96];
knex('products')
    .whereIn('code', codeProducts)
    .then((results) => {
        // response to api call
        console.log(results);
    });
```

### Approach: 2 (I don't like this approach. Too many call on db)

```
async function getData(codes) {
    try {
        let results = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < codes.length; i++) {
            let dbQuery = await knex('products').where('code', codes[i]).first();
            results.push(dbQuery);
        }
        return results;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}


const codeProducts = [54, 95];
getData()
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = codeProducts.map((code, index) => {

    return app.db('products').where('code',code).first()
    .then(result => {
        return {
        code: code,
        quantity: result.quantity
      }
    }) 
})  


return data
```

This code should fix your problem. You are accessing the quantity outside of the promise. In order to set the quantity on the data array, you need to do it inside the then

Comment: Checkout my new version, I think now it's ok, i wanted map not foreach

Comment: I'm not being able to find an answer.

Comment: I needed the return for the promise too in order to propagate the result, my bad

Comment: look error

[ Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined },
  Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined } ]